# Распечатать страницу html - обрезается все, кроме первой страницы. Как исправить?

Tags: css3, печать, print

Такая проблема. При отправке на печать страницы html данные обрезаются. 
Распечатывается только первая страница из нескольких. А остальные почему-то не печатаются. Документ просто обрезается. Причем, может обрезаться по середине высоты строки текста.

Подскажите, как и что нужно поменять в html(5)/css(3) чтобы документ нормально распечатывался?

Пока у меня в файле стилей для печати указано только

```
.noprint { display: none; }
.print { display: block; }
```

В html, соответственно, эти классы блокам присвоены.

Answer (score 1):

без кода сложно сказать, но попробуйте:

```
@media print {
    .print {
        display: inline;        
    }
}
```

и / или

```
@media print {
    .print {
        overflow: visible;  
        overflow-y: visible;      
    }
}
```